# C++ const reference to class member variable assigned in ctor

Tags: c++

In C++, is this going to work as expected, or will be there undefined behaviour in some cases

```
class Foo 
{
public:
   const int & ref;
   Foo() : ref(val) { val = 7; }
   void SetVal(int v) { val = v; }

private:
   int val;
}
```

And I expect that `ref` will "contain" value of `val`.

Why I am doing this... baceuse I want the variable to be read only from outside, but "assignable" from inside the class.

Comment: A somewhat safer solution would be `int ref() const { return val; }`. With the current approach, it would be valid for a user to say `const_cast<int&>(x.ref) = 0;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's `const` for a reason though :(

Comment: It looks okay for simple classes, there is more maintenance needed for more complex classes (multi constructors, assignment/move operators)

Comment: be careful, because a const reference is not free. It will take space in your struct and the compiler is not allowed to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work as expected. `val` will have a valid location the moment you set `ref` to it. From then on, `ref` will just hold whatever is in `val`.